# Errors in my code using do/while

Tags: java

I am a student (big time "Newbie") learning java. The two examples below are in fact homework. Example 1 is a game of guess the card (black or red) and Example 2 is a game of rock, paper ,scissors.

I have searched this site for answers, and the responses I have seen go out of context with where we are in our curiculum. At this point we are in do/while, while & for loops.

This is the code I came up with (no small feat for me) that I would like to have debuged. I do not care about making it more efficient or anything of the like. I am more concerned with having it work. I am using netbeans and I have put (<---)'s where there seems to be a problem. Your help would be greatly appriciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S. The course is in french, so do not be suprised if some of the variable names do not make sense.

EX1------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    package devoir.pkg3;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Dev3Ex4 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            char r = 'r', n = 'n', q = 'q';
            int i, compteur = 0, compteurDeux = 0;

            do {
                System.out.println("Deviner la couleur de la carte. \"r\" rouge, \"n\" noire et \"q\" quitter.");
                char clavier = scanner.next().charAt(0);
                i = (int) (2.0 * Math.random());
                compteur = compteur + 1;

                if (i == 0) {
                    char tmp = 'n';
                }
                if (i == 1) {
                    char tmp = 'r';
                }
                if (clavier == tmp) {                 <------ (temp value error)
                    compteurDeux = compteurDeux + 1;
                    System.out.println("Bon choix ! Score: " + compteurDeux + "/" + compteur);
                }
                if (clavier != tmp) {                 <------ (temp value error)
                    System.out.println("Non...Score: " + compteurDeux + "/" + compteur);
                }
            } while (clavier != 'q');                 <------ (clavier value error)
            System.out.println("Votre score final est " + compteurDeux + "/" + compteur);
        }
    }
```

EX2------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
package devoir.pkg3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dev3Ex5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         char q = 'q';
         int i, compteur = 0, compteurDeux = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Jouons a Roche/papier/ciseaux. \"r\" roche, \"p\" papier. \"c\" ciseax et \"q\" quitter.");
            char clavier = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            i = (int) (3.0 * Math.random());

            if (clavier == 'r') {
                int tmp = 0;
            }
            if (clavier == 'c') {
                int tmp = 1;
            }
            if (clavier == 'p') {
                int tmp = 2;
            }
            if (tmp == 0 && i == 1 || tmp == 1 && i == 2 || tmp == 2 && i == 0) {<--(All tmp values error)
                compteur = compteur + 1;
                System.out.println("Bon choix ! Score: " + compteur + "/" + compteurDeux);
            }
            if (tmp == 1 && i == 0 || tmp == 2 && i == 1 || tmp == 0 && i == 2) {<--(All tmp values error)
                compteurDeux = compteurDeux + 1;
                System.out.println("Non...Score: " + compteur + "/" + compteurDeux);
            }
            if (tmp == i) { <--(tmp value error)
                System.out.println("Parti nul. Score " + compteur + "/" + compteurDeux);
            }
        } while (clavier != 'q'); <--(clavier value error)
        System.out.println("Votre score final est " + compteur + "/" + compteurDeux);          
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll tell you the issue is with scope on a local variable. Since it's homework, I'll let you do the research =)

Comment: if there is error in your code..than correct it ur self..;)

Comment: At the first <----- what would the variable tmp be if i == 2?

Comment: Taking a wider view, you have far too much non-working code in one chunk. When learning a new language, and especially when learning to program for the first time, it is better to work in small pieces, and get each piece working, building up gradually.

Comment: @jervine10 Very admirable, unfortunately others have spoon-fed the OP the answer below :(

Comment: @jervine10 When people are like, "here's my homework, please do it for me", I'm like... no. On the other hand, when people are clear that something is homework, but still have a very specific question they're confused about, I don't see any issue with answering that question regardless of what it's for?

Answer (score 1):

You have problems with your local variable declaration inside code blocks

```
if (i == 0) {
    char tmp = 'n';
}
if (i == 1) {
    char tmp = 'r';
}
```

Change it to something like this:

```
char tmp='';
if (i == 0) {
    tmp = 'n';
}
if (i == 1) {
    tmp = 'r';
}
```

Same for `char clavier` and `int tmp` - declare & define them first before using them, usually at the start of your function, so that all your variables will be in one place.

**Note: This is considered to be best practice to define variables at the top of your Method and class block.**

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is one of scope: when you define `char tmp = 'n'` inside of an if { } block, that variable tmp is available for use *only* inside of that block. You need to define char tmp outside of the series of if statements, then simply specify its value inside them, like:

```
char tmp = ' ';
if (i == 0) {
  tmp = 'n';
}
else if (i == 1) {
  tmp = 'r';
}
```

etc.

Same thing for your clavier variable in both examples, which are declared inside the do {} block, and will thus be available only inside that block, not in the control for the block.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You defined char tmp outside of the if statements, then redefined it within the if statements. This will in fact give you separate variables.

Comment: @sakura Thanks, you are in fact correct. What I get for copy-pasting his code in a hurry.

Comment: Thank you all for your speedy replies. I did not post this to cheat on my homework. I posted it cause I am having trouble understanding how it all works and this community has a strong reputation. I will go back to work on it, defining the variables outside of the if blocks.

Comment: Ok so with some brilliant help, the problems were resolved. The code works. :) I'll post it after the 8 hour restriction in place by this site.

Answer (score 0):

1.`char tmp` has to be declared outside the block as shown below.

```
char tmp;
if (i == 0) {
    tmp = 'n';
}
if (i == 1) {
    tmp = 'r';
}
```

Same with `clavier`, has to be declared outside `do` to be used in the while condition.

```
char clavier
do{
```

2.Same with the second program. declare the tmp values outside and then use them.